# Couchbase Elastic Connector checkoint issue

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, connector

Our configuration has two connectors. Each connector is connected to its own elasticsearch. But the two connectors are reading from the same couchbase bucket. We have noticed that if one of the connector is started first and reads all of the documents from the bucket, then the second connector after starting is not able to feed anything into its elasticsearch. Could this be due to checkpoint document added by first connector into the source bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the two connectors have different group names, otherwise they will share the same replication checkpoint (and weird things will happen if they run at the same time).

Here's the relevant section of the config file:

```
[group]
  name = 'example-group'
```

> Each connector group must be assigned a unique name (in order to keep its replication checkpoints separate). The group name is required even if there is only one connector instance in the group.

Reference: https://docs.couchbase.com/elasticsearch-connector/4.2/configuration.html#group-membership